# Pipe-chain in clang format

Tags: c++, clang-format, std-ranges, c++23

At the moment I have some code like so:

```cpp
const auto results =
    some_container | ranges::views::transform(function1)
    | ranges::views::filter(function2) | ranges::views::filter(function3)
    | ranges::to<std::vector<ResultType>>();
```

Which I would love to be formatted as:

```cpp
const auto results = some_container
    | ranges::views::transform(function1)
    | ranges::views::filter(function2)
    | ranges::views::filter(function3)
    | ranges::to<std::vector<ResultType>>();
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make that happen in clang-format-17 though. Any help?

Comment: Does `AlignOperands: AlignAfterOperator` work? Possibly in conjunction with `BreakBeforeBinaryOperator: All` (or `NonAssignment`)

Comment: `AlignOperands: AlignAfterOperator` and `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment` were already set in my config. Using `All` instead had no relevant effect.

Comment: Sounds like a clang-format bug, since those really should do what you want per the documentation.